# How long would O(n log n) really take?

Tags: time, time-complexity

I am using a heap sort and im trying to find out about how long it will take my program to run if my input file is 11gb, but what exactly is "n" supposed to be? would it be gb, mb, kb, or something else? how can I calculate an estimated time for a given size using O(n log n)?

Comment: Big-O tells you how the complexity will change with varying values of n, but it can't give a precise value for any particular n. If you know the time it takes for other input sizes then you can extrapolate to 11gb.

Answer (score 0):

`n` is number records your passing to an algorithm and with its polynomial's degree - *the highest or the greatest power of a variable in a polynomial equation*. Here `O(n log n)` is not about actual time. if your concern is about actual time of calculation then it depends nature of input, type of machine - RAM, CPU, type of interpretes, compilers...